# Кто мне сможет объяснить небольшую часть кода?

Tags: javascript

Новичок. Пытаюсь разобраться в javascript, однако никак не пойму вот эту часть. Кто-нибудь может объяснить что здесь происходит?

```
let selectedTd;
table.onclick = function(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName != 'TD') return;
  highlight(target);
};

function highlight(td) {
  if (selectedTd) {
    selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
  selectedTd = td;
  selectedTd.classList.add('highlight');
}
```

Comment: Речь идет о таблице с подсветкой и смены цвета при клике

Comment: Добавляет класс ячейки при клике на нее (и удаляет у ранее выбранной)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Ничего хорошего. Так себе код.

Answer (score 0):

Я не силен в JS, но, насколько я вижу, этот кусочек кода выделяет выбранную ячейку в таблице при клике на ней. И удаляет выделения с предыдущей ячейки.

```
if (target.tagName != 'TD') return;
```

Это проверка что если выделена не ячейка таблицы а что-то другое, то функция не выполняется.

```
if (selectedTd) {
```

Это проверяется, была ли какая-либо ячейка выделена в таблице до клика или нет. И если до клика уже была выделена какая-то ячейка, то с нее выделение убирается, чтобы выделение повесить уже на новую ячейку

Comment: had0uken, спасибо, до меня не может дойти условие при If. Это означает: "Если вы выбрали другую ячейку, то меняется цвет"?

Comment: @Степан описание обоих IF добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо большое